# Angular 2 | How to select the 2nd letter of the value

Tags: angular, substr, angular-ng-if

Good day,

How can i select the 2nd letter of my api data using angular?

i know we can select the 2nd letter of a value using substring() or split("") in jquery. but how can i do this with angular 2/4?

lets say i have an API data

and i want to select only the 2nd letter and color it by red.

```
  <div *ngFor="let apidata of data" class="box">
    <div class="box-assignmentnumber-holder">
      <span id="AssignmentNumber">{{apidata.AssignmentNumber}}</span><br/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Example output is: 123456 | 2 should be color in red.

Comment: Use this code `<span> {{this.name[0]}}<span style="color:red">{{this.name[1]}}</span>      {{this.name.substring(2)}}  </span>`

Comment: Thanks man, itworks fine :)